# Java 8 upgrade causes compiler error with inherited static enum

Tags: java, java-8

We're upgrading a Java 6 project to Java 8. Recompiling with Java 8 gives errors in a java.awt.Frame subclass, I've simplified to the following:

org/example/Foo.java

```
package org.example;

import org.example.Type;
import java.awt.Frame;

public class Foo extends Frame {
    public Foo() {
        System.out.println(Type.BAZ);  // <=== error here, BAZ cannot be resolved
    }
}
```

org/example/Type.java

```
package org.example;

public class Type {
    public static final int BAZ = 1;
}
```

What appears to be happening is a static enum [java.awt.Window.Type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.Type.html) introduced in Java 7 is taking precedence even though there is an import for org.example.Type. Is this correct?

Does this mean we'll have to fully qualify all references to our Type with org.example.Type?

Comment: I suspect you are right and Java 8 is taking inheritance over imports. IMHO you should use a fully qualified package to be clear as to which `Type` you mean.  Or you could use a Class name which doesn't conflict with a built in class.

Comment: Changing `Type` to `MyType` worked, so I presume 'Yes' on your questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What appears to be happening is a static enum java.awt.Window.Type introduced in Java 7 is taking precedence even though there is an import for org.example.Type. Is this correct?

Yes. The `Type` class is new, but the behavior is not. This is by design, and not new to Java 8.

> Does this mean we'll have to fully qualify all references to our Type with org.example.Type?

Yes, as long as you're extending a class that contains a `Type` member.

I would question why you're extending `Frame` though: most times people extend `Frame` or `JFrame`, they shouldn't be. Favor composition over inheritance, and all that.

Another approach might be to use a static import to specifically import the `Type` members, in this case `BAZ`. something like this:

```
package org.example;

import static org.example.Type.BAZ;
import java.awt.Frame;
public class Foo extends Frame {
   public Foo() {
      System.out.println(BAZ);  
   }
}
```

That will be a pain in the neck if `Type` has a bunch of members though. Yet another approach might be to make `Type` an interface, and then have `Foo` implement that interface:

```
public interface Type {
    public static final int BAZ = 1;
}
public class Foo extends Frame implements Type{
    public Foo() {
        System.out.println(BAZ);  
    }
}
```

You could also create a `Type` instance in your `Foo` class, or rename `Type` to avoid the conflict, or create a bridge between `Foo` and `Type`.

These are all slightly hackish solutions to simply not extending Frame though.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I agree competely with JFrame over Frame and composition over inheritance,  but this is creeky 10 year old code with no unit tests,  so treading carefully and making minimal changes.